# Getting a key's value in a nested dictionary

Tags: python

I just found a now deleted question on Stack Overflow and solved the problem. The OP was asking for a way to get all the values contained by all 'PLU' keys. I solved it this way but because I am a newbie in python I was wondering if it would be an optimal/better way of doing this, maybe using iterators, I don't know.

Result should be:

```
234
32
33
334
61
```

---

```
def getPLU(data):
    for item in data:
        if type(data[item]) == dict:
            getPLU(data[item])
        else :
            if item == 'PLU':
                print (data[item])

    pass

def Main():
    times = 0
    Menu = {
      'PLU' : '234',
      'Salad': {
        'salad': {
            'ceaser':{
                'PLU': '32'
            },
            'italian':{
                'PLU': '33'
            }
        }
      },
      'Dessert': {
        'cookie': {
          'PLU': '334',
          'NAME': 'cookie ',
        }
      },
      'Appetizer': {
        'extra sauce': {
          'PLU': '61',
          'NAME': 'extra sauce',
        }
      }
    }
    getPLU(data=Menu)
    #print (getPLU(Menu))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and thanks for all the answers posted. Also thanks for the corrections made to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Great job so far! I have a few suggestions for your code:

1. Avoid writing functions with [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) such as printed output. Side effects make a function much less reusable. Instead, you may return a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) that `yield`s the next entry. This gives the caller maximum control over what to do with the result set: print it, iterate one by one, just get the first few items without searching the entire structure, etc.
2. Consider adhering more strictly to [Python naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). For example, functions should be lower_camel_cased. Since your function returns multiple PLUs, the function name seems more accurately written as `get_plus`. You can remove the `pass` keyword in your function and pay close attention to spacing, for example in the `print (data[item])` function call and your `else :` block.
3. Clean up lines like

   ```
   else :
       if item == 'PLU':
           print (data[item])
   ```

   Which is logically equivalent to:

   ```
   elif item == 'PLU':
       print(data[item])
   ```
4. Use `data.items()` to iterate through your dictionary's keys and values rather than only keys. This allows cleaner syntax to access values.
5. Make your function more general for maximum reusability. Fetching a list of values by key from a dictionary is a task that should work for any key. Why not make "PLU" a search parameter? If you want to keep the original `get_plus` version, write both functions and have `get_plus` wrap the generalized version.
6. `isinstance` may be a more [accurate choice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25232010) than `type` if you wish to allow collection subclasses of dictionary to use your function.

Here's my version for consideration:

```
def find_by_key(data, target):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            yield from find_by_key(value, target)
        elif key == target:
            yield value


def main():
    menu = {
      'PLU' : '234',
      'Salad': {
        'salad': {
            'ceaser':{
                'PLU': '32'
            },
            'italian':{
                'PLU': '33'
            }
        }
      },
      'Dessert': {
        'cookie': {
          'PLU': '334',
          'NAME': 'cookie ',
        }
      },
      'Appetizer': {
        'extra sauce': {
          'PLU': '61',
          'NAME': 'extra sauce',
        }
      }
    }

    for x in find_by_key(menu, "PLU"):
        print(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code is well organized and read well but there are a few oddities:

1. Read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and apply official coding conventions so that your code read like Python code;
2. Remove that useless `pass`;
3. Don't `print` your results in the function that compute them, instead `return` them to the caller so your function is reusable (in your case, `yield`ing them might be more appropriate);
4. Don't check for a specific type using `type`: favor `isinstance`; better would be to not check for a type at all but for a feature: call the `items` method of what would appear to be a `dict` and work with that, discard anything else that raise an `AttributeError`;
5. A more generic function would accept the key to search for as parameter;
6. A recursive approach cannot handle arbitrary large structures due to the recursion limit, an iterative approach can (even though it would rarely be an issue in practice).

Proposed improvements:

```
def retrieve_nested_value(mapping, key_of_interest):
    mappings = [mapping]
    while mappings:
        mapping = mappings.pop()
        try:
            items = mapping.items()
        except AttributeError:
            # we didn't store a mapping earlier on so just skip that value
            continue

        for key, value in items:
            if key == key_of_interest:
                yield value
            else:
                # type of the value will be checked in the next loop
                mappings.append(value)


def main():
    menu = {...}
    for plu in retrieve_nested_value(menu, 'PLU'):
        print(plu)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Nice recursive solution! Just a few suggestions:

- You should structure you entire code better and set up individual functions to set up the menu and get the prices, not do it all in `main`.
- Ideally, you would add a docstring that describes what your function does and what the parameters are. I personally like the [numpy docstring style](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html).
- Function names should be `snake_case`, not `CamelCase`, so it would be `get_plu(data)`
- `data` is a very generic term, you should use something more descriptive such as `menu`
- If you want the type comparison [to also work for inherited types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance), you should use `isinstance(data[item], dict)` instead of `type(data[item]) == dict`
- Remove the space in `print (data[item])`
- Your function should return something meaningful or `None`. Perhaps you want to also save the prices in a list or set, or you want to at least `return 0`, which commonly means that the function ran successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If you have mixtures of dict and list in your nested dict, like:

```
d = {"a": 3, 'b': [4, 5, {"c": 56}]}
```

then use:

```
def find_by_key(data, target):
    for k, v in data.items():
        if k == target:
            return v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            return find_by_key(v, target)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for i in v:
                if isinstance(i, dict):
                    return find_by_key(i, target)
```

Output:

```
find_by_key(d, "c")
56
```